# Are there any reasons why some methods in File uses boolean values to indicate its success (instead of just throwing exceptions)?

Tags: java

The `File` class in Java contain methods that utilize boolean values to indicate the successfulness of the operation being carried out. Users of said methods are required to check the return value every time it is being called.

Below is the snippet of the documentations taken from **`mkdir()`** stating the requirement:

> ***public boolean mkdir()***
>
> *Creates the directory named by this file, assuming its parents exist. Use mkdirs if you also want to create missing parents.*
>
> ***Note that this method does not throw IOException on failure. Callers
>   must check the return value.***

There's also a case with **`createNewFile()`** which (even weirder) use both boolean values as well as thrown exceptions to indicate successfulness:

> ***public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException***
>
> *Creates a new, empty file on the file system according to the path
>   information stored in this file. **This method returns true if it
>   creates a file, false if the file already existed.** Note that it
>   returns false even if the file is not a file (because it's a
>   directory, say).*
>
> *...*
>
> *Note that this method does not throw IOException if the file already
>   exists, even if it's not a regular file. **Callers should always check
>   the return value**, and may additionally want to call isFile.*

Now, this seems inconvenient at best, because the user would have to anticipate two kind of error scenarios instead of just using a simple `try-catch` block.

What's the reason behind this fuss?

Comment: It is what it is. If you cannot stand this, you can create an abstraction layer above these function that will have the behavior you want.

Comment: I can stand this just fine – I just want to know _why_ they made it this way.

Comment: @jira No you can't. You don't know the *reason* for the failure. All you have is a boolean. You don't know whether it was 'not found', 'access denied', `SecurityException`, 'I hate you', ... All you can do is throw some useless exception that is no more informative than the boolean.

Comment: not based on anything! some logics may differentiate between states that are "unexpected" to throw an exception. and plausable failures as "nothing exceptional happened... you just have that file already..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because that's the way they designed it, over twenty years ago. If you can get the developers out of their retirement homes and off their Zimmer frames you might get a better answer. Otherwise we are all just guessing.

However you don't need to call these methods as often as some people here seem to think. For example, `isFile()/exists()/delete()/createNewFile()` are all redundant before `new FileInputStream(...)` or `new FileOutputStream(...)`, which will throw exactly the exceptions you are looking for. Calling `File.exists()/delete()/createNewFile()` before either of these or the corresponding `FileReader/Writer` constructors is worse than useless, it is a positive waste of time and space, doing work that the constructor (or rather the operating system code invoked by the constructor) has to repeat. I doubt that I have ever used `File.createNewFile()` in 20 years.

Comment: I have to be honest that I was expecting a better answer than "we are all just guessing" – but I guess you're right. Now I'm inclined to make a TV series trying to find answers to these Stonehenge of programming languages.